# Can this origami figure actually be made?

Tags: origami

In [*The Arrival*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0439895294), by Shaun Tan, the protagonist makes origami, including [this bird](https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-pLVid97WNt4/Wnz5gStiDLI/AAAAAAAAAHs/BOhlBVgWaDEI4ej5Ii2pj-F_kpFwdVcXQCLcBGAs/s1600/20180208_192632.jpg).

[image]

Can that figure actually be folded, as drawn? Or did the author just draw something vaguely origami-ish?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at [Robert J. Lang's Opus 822, Northern Mockingbird](https://langorigami.com/artwork/northern-mockingbird-opus-822/), it's entirely possible to create a base for a bird model that incorporates flaps for head, wings, tail, and legs.  How easy it might be to do without being Lang or knowing a technique to create a base with the appropriate flaps for those features (e.g., [circle-packing](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.174.820&rep=rep1&type=pdf)), I don't know.